# Problem With Routes After Deploying Sinatra Application

Tags: apache2, sinatra, passenger

I wrote a simple Sinatra application with two "routes":  "/show" and "/listshows".  When I run the application on top of Webrick, everything works beautifully for both the static and non-static routes.  Here are the URL's that I use:

- http://localhost:4567/listshows
- http://localhost:4567/show?guid=someguid

Today, I deployed my simple application on top of Apache and Passenger 2.  My web server is on my private network and is named Millhouse.  I basically want to access the application using the following URLs:

- http://millhouse/slwa/listshows
- http://millhouse/slwa/show?guid=someguid

The probem is that the "slwa" string isn't part of any of my URL's.  For example, when you try to visit "http://millhouse/slwa", you should be automatically redirected to "http://millhouse/slwa/listshows".  While my app does redirect, it ends up sending me to "http://millhouse/listshows".  The "slwa" part is missing.

I didn't want to create a new virtual host, so I reused the "root" virtual host on my Ubuntu server.  Here's my virtual host:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    DocumentRoot /var/www
    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride None
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
            AllowOverride None
            Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined

    Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
    <Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
        Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
    </Directory>

    ### Here's the only line that I added to the default
    RackBaseURI /slwa
</VirtualHost>
```

I also created a symlink under /var/www that points at the public dir for my app.  And finally, here's my config.ru:

```
# This is straight from the Phusion Passnger Users Guide"
require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra'

root_dir = File.dirname(__FILE__)

set :environment, ENV['RACK_ENV'].to_sym
set :root,        root_dir
set :app_file,    File.join(root_dir, 'slwa.rb')
disable :run

require 'slwa'
run Sinatra::Application
```

What part am I missing?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Tom Purl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried redirect url(:controller, :action)?

had the same problem, that solved it for me... (except for css and js public assets...)

Comment: I ended up using the emk-sinatra-url-for package to make my URL's work. I even wrote about it on my blog - http://tompurl.com/2011/01/17/sinatra-lessons-learned/. Thanks anyways Udo!